# Is there a way to optimize this keycode list functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, keycode

I want to write it in a better, optimized way. I thought maybe I should use jquery each function but not sure how to write it. Basically there are list of 7 buttons and both NUM keys and regular number keys are attached to related buttons.
the HTML is here http://jsfiddle.net/wAwed/1/

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input') || $(".answerbtns").length != 0 ) { return }
    /* keyboard 1 */

    else if (e.keyCode == 97 || e.keyCode == 49 ) {
        $("#.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl00_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 2 */
    if (e.keyCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 50 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl01_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 3 */
    if (e.keyCode == 99 || e.keyCode == 51 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl02_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 4 */
    if (e.keyCode == 100 || e.keyCode == 52 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl03_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 5 */
    if (e.keyCode == 101 || e.keyCode == 53 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl04_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 6 */
    if (e.keyCode == 102 || e.keyCode == 54 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl05_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    /* keyboard 7 */
    if (e.keyCode == 103 || e.keyCode == 55 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl06_lbAnswers")[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: sure, create a map of keycodes that link keycodes to the target element, then use a loop. Or use object key/value pairs.

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sure, create a map of keycodes that link keycodes to the target element, then use a loop. Or use object key/value pairs. Here's a sample for two of them:

```
var keys = {
    97: "#.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl00_lbAnswers",
    49: "#.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl00_lbAnswers"
}
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input') || $(".answerbtns").length != 0 ) { return }
    /* keyboard 1 */

    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        $(keys[e.keyCode])[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

And, if they all have the class "answerbtns", you can do this:

```
var numeric = [97,98,99,100,101,102,103];
var numpad =  [49,50,51,52,53,54,55];
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input') || $(".answerbtns").length == 0 ) { return }
    /* keyboard 1 */
    var index = $.inArray(e.which,numeric);
    if ( index == -1 ) {
        index = $.inArray(e.which,numpad);
    }
    if ( index != -1 ) {
        $(".answerbtns")[index].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wAwed/2/

Comment: Is that an auto-generated id? is it safe to hardcode an autogenerated id in javascript? It certainly isn't very maintenance friendly.

Comment: Yes it is auto-generated id. I can use a class name"answerbtns" for all buttons but then i would have to use index to specific each of them? I don't really know how to achieve it yet.

Comment: Yes, you would select them all, then filter by index. For pressing 1, filter to index 0, 2 is 1 etc

Comment: I assumed you have more than one question with answers. If you did, and you used just the .answer class, you would select all answers, not just the ones related to the question the user is currently focused  on.

Comment: It depends heavily on the html structure being used, can you provide a sample of that?

Comment: @user2734550: You could mark the widgets with a particular class name, have a jQuery object containing all the widgets with that class name, and map the keyCode to an index rather than an ID...

Comment: @cHao that's exactly what my 2nd example does.

Comment: @KevinB: So it is.  :)  Hadn't seen it, actually; I just assumed some more info was needed, considering the answer was prompting more questions.

Comment: The answer was incomplete, without html i wasn't able to actually make it work. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

This option reduces some code.

```
var custKeyCode = [97, 49, 98, 50];

if (e.keyCode == 97 || e.keyCode == 49 ) {
    myid = "#.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl00_lbAnswers";
}

if (e.keyCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 50 ) {
    myid = "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrQuizQuestions_ctl01_lbAnswers";
}

......
......

for(var i=0; i<custKeyCode.length; i++){
    if(custKeyCode[i] == e.keyCode){
        $(myid)[0].click();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: you could make the conditional part shorter by using an array and searching the array

Comment: That's useful for code on which 'click' script is executing.